# Convergence in prob. and a.s.: Commonly-used strategies

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, self-learning, law-of-large-numbers

Good afternoon,

I'm typing in $\LaTeX$ a formularium and a compendium of useful probability theorems, corolaries and commonly-used approaches to many topics in preparation to an important exam at my university. Right now I'm working onto the convergence section.

I know that:

> **Convergence in probability** problems often can be solved by applying **Chebyshev's inequality** and **Khintichine's Law of Large Numbers**.
>
> **Almost-surely convergence** problems often can be solved by applying **Borel-Cantelli's Lemmas** and **Kolmogorov's Law of Large Numbers**.
>
> **Slutsky's theorem** is also nice if $X_{n} \xrightarrow[]{} X$ and $Y_{n} \xrightarrow[]{} c$, where $c$ is a constant, and  you are working with their product/sum.

I know that every single exercise has it's particularities and "sideboard" procedures, but I'd like to know if there are other theorems/results that are majorly used in those kind of problems. I would be very thankful.

Comment: Central limit theorem?